# Python List not appending items to list

Tags: python, list, append

Can't figure out why, help appreciated. It is just returning [] each time. Edited with arguments, sorry.

```
def in(f, e):
    n = len(f)
    a = 0
    b = 0 
    c = 0
    m = []
    for i in range (1, n):
        a = 0
        for j in range (0, n + 1):
            if (e[i - 1] == (j, i)):
                a = a + 1
                m.append(a)
    return m

print(in([1, 2, 3] , [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)]))
```

Comment: what is being passed in as `f` and `e`?

Comment: Your function overwrites the builtin `in` operator..

Comment: I think you need to indent everything (except the return) after the first for loop. Also, we need to know what `f` and `e` as Tim said.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to name a method `in` due to it being a keyword, but I don't think that it breaks it here since your `in` takes parameters.

Comment: @Clete2: The program won't execute at all `def in(...)` is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: The condition in your `if` statement is never true for the inputs you provided.  Double check your logic and/or change inputs as necessary.

Comment: If you add a print before or after your `if` clause you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're right. My mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for j in range (0, n + 1):
    print e[i - 1],
    print (j, i)
    if (e[i - 1] == (j, i)):
```

I added these two prints for testing purposes and below is their output. (I'm using python 2.7, hence the statements instead of functions, but that doesn't really make a difference)

```
(1, 2) (0, 1)
(1, 2) (1, 1)
(1, 2) (2, 1)
(1, 2) (3, 1)
(2, 1) (0, 2)
(2, 1) (1, 2)
(2, 1) (2, 2)
(2, 1) (3, 2)
```

As you can see, `e[i - 1]` is never equal to `(j, i)`, therefore it won't ever enter the `if` block and won't append items to your list, so it stays empty and your function returns `[]`.

Btw, I also had to change the function name because as mentioned in the comments, `def in(f, e):` produces a SyntaxError.